# Problem implementing a custom AWS Lambda Runtime

Tags: python-3.x, dockerfile, aws-lambda-containers

I am trying to implement a custom runtime in AWS Lambda.

I have built the dockerfile and it runs in my local environment fine, including with the aws-lambda-rie.  Running the built image locally like this, works fine.

```
docker run -p 9000:8080 myImage
```

And I know it works fine becuase if I poke it with Postman, I can see the code within the container running as expected:

```
http://127.0.0.1:9000/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations
```

When I upload the image to AWS ECR and create an AWS Lambda function using that image though, it fails very quickly with a not-all-that-helpful error message.

```
Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 1
```

I gather this is all related to filestructures and entrypoints, but I can't fathom it...  In my dockerfile, I have this:

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "/home/entry_script.sh" ]
CMD [ "app.main" ]
```

app.py is inside /home/

Inside entry_script.sh, I have:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -z "${AWS_LAMBDA_RUNTIME_API}" ]; then
  exec /usr/bin/aws-lambda-rie/aws-lambda-rie python3 -m awslambdaric $@
else
  exec /usr/bin/python3 -m awslambdaric $@
fi
```

The aws-lambda-rie part of this, which runs when the image is on my local machine, seems fine as the code runs.  I can't really tell what's happening though when I try to run this in Lambda.

I'm going wrong somewhere, but can't spot it...  please help.

Thank you.

Comment: This looks to be an issue with the library(s) I'm using not playing nicely with Lambda and/or awslambdaric.  The library authors are looking in to it.  I'll update back here when I know more.